# how to make a list out of bullet points

Tags: java, android

```
public void printStarterservices(View view) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.smartliving_text))
      .setText("• Personal Care Services" + "• HouseHold Task" +
               "• Shopping Tasks" + "• Rehabilitation" +
               "• Smart Living" + "• Respite & Befriending Care" +
               "• Walking or Sleep overnight" + "• Cleaning" +
               "• Bed making and more");
}
```

Comment: Use a `WebView`. Or, use `SpannableStringBuilder` and `BulletSpan` to create the text to go into the `TextView()`.

Answer (score 1):

The by far easiest way would be to just add `\n` newline characters between your items.

```
// ...
"• Personal Care Services" + "\n\n" +
"• HouseHold Task"
```

This will resolve in a new line for each item.

Alternatives to this are

- Using HTML text `<ul>` and `<li>` with [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) to format the TextView
- Having multiple TextViews in a LinearLayout or ListView
- Using a webview and displaying html content